# How to get IP value from textarea with regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Here is a textarea.(IPv4, Domain)

```
96.17.109.65 fox.com
```

And I want to change IP value into another one.
like this,

```
74.125.71.106 fox.com
```

I guess it will be like

```
$('textarea').find('some regular expressions..').val('another one...');
```

Please help me. I just wanna learn regular expressions.. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matching an IP address using regular expression is not as easy as it sounds. There are two methods available:

**simple, but can lead to false-positives:**

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

**complex, but always correct:**

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

If you want to replace it, you'll need something like this (using the simple RegExp as an example):

```
var textarea = $('textarea');
textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b/g, '74.125.71.106'));
```

Answer (score 2):

This uses a basic regex to find the seperator between ip and domain, it doesn't validate but it should do want you need:

```
var newIP = '74.125.71.106';
var $t = $('textarea');
$t.val($t.val().replace(/^([^\s]+)/mg, newIP + ' '));
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exaclty what I wanted. A quite simple answer, but works perfect!